# find all .xls file mobile and list then . ( android )

Tags: android, android-file

i am developing a app in which i want to list all .xls (excel files ) . 
How can i find all .xls find in storage (both internal and external ) ? 
And after getting the list i want to read the xls file , 
the file has only two columns , how to read data from that xls file row by row .
the file has one column for name of a person and other for her/his address.
I want to read data from that file and save it to mobile .

tell me how can i find all xls file s and how to read a xls file .
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Give the permission in your app manifesto:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />
```

**Get SD_CARD path:**

```
String SDCARD_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/";
```

**Call getXLSFiles():**

```
getXLSFiles(SDCARD_PATH);
```

**In your Activity:**

```
ArrayList<String> FOLDERS = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> XLS_FILES = new ArrayList<String>();

int CALL_COUNT = 0;

public void getXLSFiles(String path) {



    try {

            File dirFolder = new File(path);
            File[] folders = dirFolder.listFiles();

            for (File file : folders) {
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    FOLDERS.add(path + file.getName() + "/");
                } else {

                    if (file.getName().contains(".xls")) {

                        XLS_FILES.add(path + file.getName());


                    } else {
                        // FILE_PATH = path + file.getName();
                        // Log.e("File Deatils", "" + FILE_PATH);
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        while (CALL_COUNT < FOLDERS.size()) {
            String dirURL = FOLDERS.get(CALL_COUNT);
            CALL_COUNT++;

            // Log.e("Folders", "" + dirURL);
            getSdCardFolders(dirURL);
        }

}
```

And you will get all .xls file in XLS_FILES list. Finally generate the listview as you want.

Comment: analysisAudioFiles(path + file.getName(),file.getName(), ".xls");
what is this ? IDE is giving error "canot resolve analysisAudioFiles "

Answer (score 0):

You can find file from both of  directory removable storage or non removable storage [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal)

And than how about searching:

You can check is that directory or file If is it directory than scan whole directory with your file extension mean end with".xls" same process will do for another directory.